# Laravel Eloquent firstOrCreate method error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try create new Model instance with `Model::firstOrCreate`, and i get error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found`.

My **code snippet**:

```
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $order = 
    Order::firstOrCreate([
       ['name' => 'John'],
       [
           'type' => 'foo',
           'start' => $date,
       ]
    ]);
```

The code above will return an error:

```
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'John' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where (`John` is null and `foo` = 2022-09-20 15:15:54) and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)
```

My attention has been drawn next piece: `` select * from `orders` where (`John` is null and ... `` Eloquent substituted the value - *John* as a search column in the query, and I expected it to be a key *name*.

[This official documentation about this method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models)

What's my mistake?

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one extra pair of `[]`.

Try like this:

```
$order = Order::firstOrCreate(
    ['name' => 'John'],
    ['type' => 'foo','start' => $date]
);
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks you. I am sorry. I'm not attentive.